# Twitter Bootstrap for GWT is not working

Tags: gwt, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Twitter Bootstrap for GWT and get the same nice and pretty view like the showcase [here](http://nyao.github.com/bootstrap4gwt/)  and here is what I did:

1- downloaded the module from [git](https://github.com/nyao/bootstrap4gwt)

2- run package task in the pom.xml

3- included the created jar in my projects classpath.

4- inherited the module in my project.gwt.xml file with

```
<inherits name="com.github.nyao.bootstrap4gwt.Bootstrap"/>
```

5- included the module in my root xml

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
             xmlns:m='urn:import:com.clouway.exreport.client.accountcreation.view'
             xmlns:t='urn:import:com.github.nyao.bootstrap4gwt.client.ui'
        >

  <ui:style src="newRegistrationStyle.css"/>
  <g:HTMLPanel addStyleDependentNames="{style.mainPanel}">
    <div class="{style.headdistance}"/>
    <div class="{style.container}">

      <g:DecoratorPanel addStyleDependentNames="{style.decoratorPanel}">

        <g:VerticalPanel addStyleDependentNames="{style.verticalPanel}}">

          <m:AccountEditor ui:field="accountEditor"/>

          <!--<g:Button ui:field="create" text="create"/>-->
         <t:Button type="Success"   text="sing in"/>
          <g:Label ui:field="errorsLabel"/>
...

</ui:UiBinder>
```

But nothing happened. I got normal text box and normal button.

[image]
I took a look at [this](http://www.aceevo.com/gwt-2-x-tutorial-with-mongodb-morphia-requestfactory-activities-and-places-editors-cell-tablelist-and-twitter-bootstrap-part-1/) tutorial which is very good and the guy got the things right, his application has very nice look. I took a look at his code but didn't find any reason why my look i still normal and he got the nice view. thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using bootstrap4gwt try using [gwtbootstrap](http://gwtbootstrap.github.com/) which is far better and has much more components compared to the former. The forum is also very active in gwtbootstrap.

Comment: also, the bootstrap4gwt team are now working with us in gwtbootstrap. Let we know if you have any issues or found any bug. Cheers